Action of a matrix group on symmetric tensor powers
$SL(2,\mathbb K)$ is said to act on the second symmetric tensor power of $\mathbb K^2$,denoted by $S^2(\mathbb K^2)$in the following fashion: We let $\rho$ denote the action and $\rho (g) (\Sigma_i x_i \otimes y_i) = gx_i \otimes gy_i$, where $g \in SL(2,\mathbb K), \Sigma_i x_i \otimes y_i \in S^2(\mathbb K^2)$. Now, how do we move down from a summation to a single element? For which particular $i$ do we compute
$gx_i \otimes gy_i$?

Isn't it just a typo? RHS should be $\sum_{i} g x_{i} \otimes g y_{i}$.

The sum was just forgotten. So no worries about "down from a summation".

What exactly do you mean by "down from a summation"? Maybe more context for this problem would help

@AndreasCaranti Should have guessed it is a typo. Otherwise, it doesn't make much sense.

@Chase I mean that since the initial element is a sum, how do we choose a component in the final result? Apologies for the handwavy language. The confusion has been cleared in the previous comments.
